# Order of execution in Python methods

Tags: python

I've tried looking at a few different examples, but I'm not really sure why this isn't working. Say I've some code like this:

```
def loadVariable():
    global count
    count = 0

def loadDictionary():
    location = 'some location'
    global myDict
    myDict = pickle.load(open(location, 'rb'))

def main():
    loadVariable()
    loadDictionary()
    for item in myDict:
        if item.startswith("rt"):
            count += 1
            item = item[3:]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

To my eyes, the if statement is executed which starts the main() method. Then, the variable which is global is loaded, the dictionary is loaded and the for loop is executed.

However, when I run the code I am told that the local variable count is referenced before its assignment. Why is that happening?

**Edit (Explaining some of the things I've written in comments):**

This doesn't work (although I think that's because global is used wrong here):

```
global count

def loadVariables()
    count = 0

def main():
    loadVariables()
    rest of code etc
```

This doesn't work either:

```
def loadVariables()
    count = 0

def main():
    global count
    loadVariables()
    rest of code etc
```

The only way thus far I've gotten it to work is using the link provided above, which is to treat the count as a list, like so:

```
def loadVariables():
    global count
    count = [0]

def main():
    loadVariables():
    rest of code etc
        count[0] += 1
```

Comment: There's no variable called `count` anywhere. I think you're misunderstanding how `global` works.

Comment: @PhillipCloud No, that part works fine. `loadVariable` creates a global variable `count`, and `loadDictionary` created a global variable `myDict`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`global` means that *within the function containing the* `global` *declaration*, the name in the `global` declaration refers to a global variable. It does not mean "this thing is a global variable; treat it as global everywhere." In `main`, the names `count` and `myDict` refer to local variables, because `main` does not declare that it wants to use the globals.

Comment: So another question. If I put "global count" at the top of the main method, and then use the loadVariable() method to do: "count = 1", why does it still return the same error?

Comment: @AndrewMartin: You probably removed the `global` declaration from `loadVariable`, in which case `count = 1` assigns to a variable local to `loadVariable`. The scope of a variable is completely unaffected by what function called the current function; `global count` in `main` doesn't affect `loadVariable`.

Comment: So I would need to reference global in BOTH main and loadVariables?

Comment: Yes. That said, you shouldn't be using global variables for this. If you want to pass information into a function, pass it as an argument. If you want to get information out of a function, return it.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. Was messing around and just trying to learn some more.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're not declaring `count` as a global variable in the `main` function, so when the compiler sees that you're (eventually) assigning to it, it assumes that it's a local variable. Since it's value is read before it's assigned, you get an exception.

So, the most basic fix is just to add `global count` at the top of `main()`, but I think avoiding globals would be a better option. Why not have `loadVariable` and `loadDictionary` return their results, rather than assigning them to globals? If in `main()` you did `count = loadVariable()`, count would be a local variable, and you'd have no problems later trying to reassign it.

Comment: The original reason was because I've simplified this example. In reality, seven or eight variables are loaded in that method. I did try to add global count to the top of the method and inside loadVariables() do count = 0, but I still get the error.

Comment: Well, then post all the code.  If you do the correction suggested by @Blcknght to the one you did post, it works correctly.

Comment: @MarioRossi: Just posted it

Comment: So after reading the other answer provided, I'd need to put global count at the top of both main AND the loadVariable method?

Comment: @AndrewMartin: You need to keep the global statement in `loadVariables` too, not just move it to `main`. Each function has it's own scope, so if you're assigning to a global in more than one function, you need to use the `global` statement in each one.

Comment: Got it. I was treating it like static in java and wondering why it didn't apply everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of how `global` works

```
global_var = 0

def updater():
    global global_var
    global_var += 1


def stuff(x):
    updater()
    return global_var + x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    stuff(2)  # returns 3
```